# How to I get df.to_csv() to stop breaking my row over multiple lines in the output file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame which contains a long np array as one of the elements. When I write it to csv using the `to_csv()` function each row is broken up over multiple lines in the output file. Is there a way to suppress this behavior and get each row of the DataFrame to only take up one line in my output csv?

```py
## Create Example Data Frame
fruit_veg = pd.DataFrame({"category":["fruit","vegetable"],
                          "items":[np.array(["apple","pear","banana","grapefruit","watermelon",
                                             "lychee","dragonfruit","mango"]),
                                   np.array(["asparags","cabbage","zuchinni","broccoli",
                                             "cauliflower","carrot","celery"])]})

## Output to csv
fruit_veg.to_csv(r'/my/file/path/EXAMPLE_PROBLEM.csv')
```

The resulting csv file (*actually*) looks like this:

```
,category,items
0,fruit,"['apple' 'pear' 'banana' 'grapefruit' 'watermelon' 'lychee' 'dragonfruit'
 'mango']"
1,vegetable,"['asparags' 'cabbage' 'zuchinni' 'broccoli' 'cauliflower' 'carrot'
 'celery']"
```

I **want** it to look like this:

```
,category,items
0,fruit,"['apple' 'pear' 'banana' 'grapefruit' 'watermelon' 'lychee' 'dragonfruit' 'mango']"
1,vegetable,"['asparags' 'cabbage' 'zuchinni' 'broccoli' 'cauliflower' 'carrot' 'celery']"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TLDR

Prevent this line wrapping by increasing numpy's `linewidth` before writing `to_csv()`:

```py
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=100000)
fruit_veg.to_csv('fruit_veg.csv')
```

---

#### Explanation

`to_csv()` writes the array's `__str__()` output which includes a [line break every 75 characters by default](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions):

> **linewidth : *int, optional***
>
> The number of characters per line for the purpose of inserting line breaks (default 75).

```py
fruit_veg.loc[0, 'items'].__str__()

# "['apple' 'pear' 'banana' 'grapefruit' 'watermelon' 'lychee' 'dragonfruit'\n 'mango']"
```

So increase the `linewidth` with [**`np.set_printoptions()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) to prevent the 75-char line breaks:

```py
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=100000)
fruit_veg.loc[0, 'items'].__str__()

# "['apple' 'pear' 'banana' 'grapefruit' 'watermelon' 'lychee' 'dragonfruit' 'mango']"
```

And the csv will come out as desired:

```py
fruit_veg.to_csv('fruit_veg.csv')

# ,category,items
# 0,fruit,['apple' 'pear' 'banana' 'grapefruit' 'watermelon' 'lychee' 'dragonfruit' 'mango']
# 1,vegetable,['asparags' 'cabbage' 'zuchinni' 'broccoli' 'cauliflower' 'carrot' 'celery']
```

Comment: Dag Nabbit! I was hoping to snag my own best answer on this one. You gotta recognize game when you see it though. Well earned. It's exactly what I was banging my head against.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is the best answer. If someone can address the issue by passing parameters to `to_csv()` instead of going in and changing the data type stored in the "items" column, I'll award the internet points to them.

#### My solution

It seems like the `df.to_csv()` function **doesn't** wrap the lines in the output file when the collection in the items column is a `list` (*instead of the `np.ndarray` that's there now*)

```py
## Recast the elements of the "items" column to lists
fruit_veg["items"] = fruit_veg["items"].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())

## Output to csv
fruit_veg.to_csv(r'/my/file/path/EXAMPLE_PROBLEM.csv')
```

The output then becomes:

```
,category,items
0,fruit,"['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'grapefruit', 'watermelon', 'lychee', 'dragonfruit', 'mango']"
1,vegetable,"['asparags', 'cabbage', 'zuchinni', 'broccoli', 'cauliflower', 'carrot', 'celery']"
```